# Powershell: Selecting DataGridView Row

Tags: arrays, powershell, datagridview

So far I have this code.

```powershell
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(900,600)
$dataGridView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
$dataGridView.Size=New-Object System.Drawing.Size(800,400)
$go = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$go.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,450)
$go.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$go.text = "Select"
$form.Controls.Add($go)
$form.Controls.Add($dataGridView)


$dataGridView.ColumnCount = 4
$dataGridView.ColumnHeadersVisible = $true
$dataGridView.Columns[0].Name = "Name"
$dataGridView.Columns[1].Name = "ID"
$dataGridView.Columns[2].Name = "Description"
$dataGridView.Columns[3].Name = "Memory"

$dataGridView.Columns[0].width = 240

get-process | foreach {
    $dataGridView.Rows.Add($_.Name,$_.ID,$_.Description,$_.WorkingSet) | out-null
}

$go.Add_Click({
    $selectedRow = $dataGridView.CurrentRowIndex
write-host $selectedRow
})

[void]$form.ShowDialog()
```

It simply gets the Process Name, ID, etc. properties and puts them into pre-defined headers in a `DataGridView`.

My problem is that I want to see the row I've clicked on via `$selectedRow = $dataGridView.CurrentRowIndex` and output it to the console. Instead, when the 'Select' button is pushed, a blank string is output to the terminal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also get the row index with:

```
$dataGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex
```

or

```
$dataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Index
```

You may also want to set the grid MultiSelect property to $false. Currently it allows  multiple rows selection. Another thing to consider is setting the SelectionMode property to 'FullRowSelect'. When the grid is populated the first column is selected, not the whole row.

Comment: Thanks Shay. I should of mentioned in the post that what I'm really after is the data (in this case the process ID) of the selected row. How would one go about doing this?

Comment: $dataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells['id'].Value

Comment: One last thing. Is it possible to select multiple rows? Something like - $dataGridView.selectedrows.Cells['id'].Value

Comment: Yes: $dataGridView.SelectedRows | Foreach { write-host  $dataGridView.Rows[$_.Index].Cells['Id'].Value}

Comment: Sorry Shay, it doesn't seem to work for me. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes I did try it, using your original code. I updated the Add_Click handler code with it, ran it, selected a few rows and clicked the Select button . All related Id's were written to the host.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
$selectedRow = $dataGridView.CurrentRowIndex
```

to

```
$selectedRow = $dataGridView.CurrentRow.Index
```