# Can I assign Variables from selected Row using out-gridview -passthru

Tags: csv, powershell, gridview

I'm very new to PowerShell and I'm trying to build on older batch files that I made into PowerShell and add some features.

At the moment I have a CSV file which I've used in the pass as a sort of "environment" file, previously I would do batch jobs against this CSV file.

I have a line

```
Import-Csv "csvfile" | select-object -property * | out-gridview -passthru
```

The CSV file is built something like:

```
Name,location,folder  
Test,e,Testsite  
Test1,c,windows  
test2,c,temp
```

Basically I want to select one of the grows and click Okay and assign the 3 items to variables.. `$foldername,$driveLetter,$destinationDirectory`

I've looked high and low and I can't seem to manage it I did find [one example on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11493700/powershell-selecting-datagridview-row) which I shamelessly copied, massaged and got to work ... but that gridview is prebuilt by the OP of that post and doesn't have things like the piping to `grid-view`.`-Passthru` has (Filter & scroll bar) but I was able to assign variables using this method but my CSV is pretty huge and I want to be able to have it auto size itself and filter / scroll.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `-OutPutMode Single` option of `Out-Gridview` to restrict selection to a single item from the gridview.

```
Import-Csv "csvfile" |
 select-object -property * |
  out-gridview -OutputMode Single -Title 'Select a row' |
  ForEach-Object {
   $foldername,$driveLetter,$destinationDirectory = $_.Name,$_.location,$_.folder
  }
```

Comment: You sir are a godsend .... I took a 2 day course on this but it was more just about getting got know commands and while the teacher was good to answer my questions ... I didn't know what I wanted to do then now I do lol.

Comment: I've always just used -passthru.  The help says that -passthru is equivalent to "-OutputMode multiple".

Comment: @MikeShepard - did they change that?  IIRC -passthru used to pass everything down the pipeline without giving you the opportunity to select anything.

Comment: Nope.  Passthru has always allowed you to select what is output.  OutputMode lets you say whether you want single or multi-select.